# Algorithm for coin game

Tags: c, algorithm, recursion

I have a problem to figure out algotrithm for this.

Given N coins for two players playing a game. Coins have different values. Each player can pick 1 or 2 coins in each turn. The player with bigger value of coins wins. Players can pick coins only from the beginning or the end of the array. Both players are playing perfectly.

for example

```
Input:
-11 5 3 6 -1
Output:
A (-1)
B (6,3)
A (5)
B (-11)
A: 4, B: -2

Input:
-34 -1 94 111 43 78 -79 13
Output:
A (13)
B (-79,78)
A (43,111)
B (94,-1)
A (-34)
A: 133, B: 92
```

I'd be glad if anyone could help me with it.. I've found various posts about algorithms where player can pick only one coin, but none with more. Thanks!

Comment: Do you know the logic behind the example input and output?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I cant figure out algorithm for that

Comment: An exhaustive Mini-Max will definitely do. Maybe there are smarter algorithms.

Comment: So some _coins_ have a negative value?

Comment: Looks like each turn, a player has 3 choices: left, right, left+right --- Min/Max tree sounds right.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica It makes it trickier for all kinds of greedy algorithms, Search algorithms won't care though

Comment: This is a form of [Nim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nim). Are you looking for a strategy to implement (an algorithm for optimal play that you would write code for) or an algorithm to find an optimal strategy?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Sounds like left-left, right-right also possible? Or the op omitted its restriction

Answer (score 1):

Use [minimax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimax) to find the optimal moves. This will tell you who wins, and if you follow the best moves, also shows perfect play.

At each moment in time, there are at most 5 available moves (using `start` as the index of the 1st coin in the array, and `end` as the index immediately after the last coin):

- you can take a coin from the start: `coins += array[start++]`
- one from the end: `coins += array[--end]`
- one from each (only if 2 or more): `coins += array[start++] + array[--end]`
- two from the start (only if 2 or more; if only 2, equivalent to previous): * one from each (only if 2 or more): `coins += array[start++] + array[start++]`
- or two from the end (only if 2 or more; if only 2, equivalent to previous 2): `coins += array[--end] + array[--end]`

With the above move-generation, and chaning `start` and `end` prior to recursion, implementing the pseudocode found in Wikipedia (or any other source) should be straightforward. I like the equivalent [negamax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negamax) variant, as it is somewhat simpler to implement.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it by dynamic programming.

Let `a` denotes the input elements, `n=length(a)`.
Let `f[i,j]` denotes the maximum result of S(Pl1)-S(Pl2) when the first i coins and the last (n-j) coins were taken, `g[i,j]` denotes the minimum result of S(Pl1)-S(Pl2).

```
f[i,j] = max{g[i+1,j]+a[i], g[i+2,j]+a[i]+a[i+1], g[i+1,j-1]+a[i]+a[j], g[i,j-2]+a[j]+a[j-1], g[i,j-1]+a[j]}
g[i,j] = min{f[i+1,j]-a[i], f[i+2,j]-a[i]-a[i+1], ...}
```

The idea is that the best strategy for remaining coins is independent to how the other coins were taken.

The function can be simplified by replacing `g[i,j]` with `-f[i,j]`, as the only difference between `g` and `f` is the order of taking coins.

Here is naive C implementation:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct record{
    int lDelta, rDelta;
    int score;
};

void checkAndUpdate(int value, int* addr, struct record *rec, int ld, int rd, int s) {
    if (value > *addr) {
        *addr = value;
        rec->lDelta = ld;
        rec->rDelta = rd;
        rec->score = s;
    }
};

int main() {
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    int a[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        scanf("%d", a + i);

    int f[n][n];
    memset(f, 128, sizeof(f));
    struct record r[n][n];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        if (i > 0)
            f[i][i-1] = 0;
        checkAndUpdate(a[i], &f[i][i], &r[i][i], 1, 0, a[i]);
    }
    for (int l = 1; l < n; ++l) {
        for (int i = 0; i + l < n; ++i) {
            checkAndUpdate(-f[i + 1][i + l] + a[i], &f[i][i + l], &r[i][i + l], 1, 0, a[i]);
            checkAndUpdate(-f[i + 2][i + l] + a[i] + a[i + 1], &f[i][i + l], &r[i][i + l], 2, 0, a[i] + a[i + 1]);
            checkAndUpdate(-f[i + 1][i + l - 1] + a[i] + a[i + l], &f[i][i + l], &r[i][i + l], 1, 1, a[i] + a[i + l]);
            checkAndUpdate(-f[i][i + l - 2] + a[i + l - 1] + a[i + l], &f[i][i + l], &r[i][i + l], 0, 2, a[i + l - 1] + a[i + l]);
            checkAndUpdate(-f[i][i + l - 1] + a[i + l], &f[i][i + l], &r[i][i + l], 0, 1, a[i + l]);
        }
    }

    int lB = 0, rB = n - 1;
    int pl = 1;
    int score[2];
    memset(score, 0, sizeof(score));
    while (lB != rB) {
        printf("PL%d take %d from the left side, %d from the right side, current score=%d\n", pl, r[lB][rB].lDelta, r[lB][rB].rDelta, score[pl-1]+=r[lB][rB].score);
        int tmp = r[lB][rB].lDelta;
        rB -= r[lB][rB].rDelta;
        lB += tmp;
        pl = 3 - pl;
    }
    printf("PL%d takes the remaing coins, score=%d\n", pl, score[pl-1]+=r[lB][rB].score);
    printf("Final score:\tPL1=%d, Pl2=%d\t\n", score[0], score[1]);
}
```

running result：

```
Input:
5
-11 5 3 6 -1

Output:
PL1 take 0 from the left side, 1 from the right side, current score=-1
PL2 take 0 from the left side, 2 from the right side, current score=9
PL1 take 0 from the left side, 1 from the right side, current score=4
PL2 takes the remaing coins, score=-2
Final score:    PL1=4, Pl2=-2
```

```
Input:
8
-34 -1 94 111 43 78 -79 13

Output:
PL1 take 0 from the left side, 1 from the right side, current score=13
PL2 take 0 from the left side, 2 from the right side, current score=-1
PL1 take 0 from the left side, 2 from the right side, current score=167
PL2 take 0 from the left side, 2 from the right side, current score=92
PL1 takes the remaing coins, score=133
Final score:    PL1=133, Pl2=92
```